# Как создать страницу 404?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

Всем привет. В laravel создал Middleware и повесил его на несколько url и при переходе обычного пользователя на эти url то его соответственно редиректит на стр 404. В рутах я написал так: `Route::get('/404', function(){return view('404'});`
А как такую страницу создать в vuejs? что для этого нужно сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В роутах пишем `{ path: '/404', component: NotFound }` 
Далее создаём компонент NotFound.